# Is it possible to search a string for base pairs using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, perl, bioinformatics

I'm trying to use regular expressions to look for RNA base pairs (ie. AU, CG, GC, UA, GU, UG) at positions within a string. I'm co-opting a Perl program that will extract characters at certain positions and looks for a match using a regular expression I provide. For example, given the string `AUGCCGU`, I could extract the first and last characters, `AU`, and then check to see if they match a regex I provide. 
Side note: I can only provide one regular expression and no other code.

Testing for a single base pair after extracting 2 characters was pretty straight forward: `(AU)|(CG)|(U[AG])|(G[CU])`. `UA = match`, `UC = no match`, etc. However, **I'm wondering if there is a reasonable way to test 4 (or more) characters and look for 1 (or more) base pair matches.** In other words: given 4 extracted characters, look for pairs between characters 1&4 and 2&3 and report a match if 1 or more pairs are found:
`ACGU = match` (2 pairs - AU, CG), `ACCU = match` (1 pair, AU), `ACUC = no match` (0 pairs).

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I feel like a combination of back references and conditionals could be required, but I'm really stuck trying to figure out how to apply them here. Or is this even possible?

Comment: By site I just meant a given position in the string. I'm telling the program to extract out characters of the string at various positions, forming a new string. The program tests the new string for matches to the regular expression. I've updated the question to (hopefully) improve clarity.

Comment: @sln I guess that was part of my question. If there is a reasonable way to write a regular expression that would accomplish this task, then it would save me from writing a script from scratch (but I'm not totally opposed to doing that). I'm just trying to gauge if that is necessary. To some extent I am generally just curious if this is something that is possible with regular expressions or if this is beyond the limits of what they are capable of doing.

Comment: *"I can only provide one regular expression and no other code"* If you have the string to match against, why can you not just split it up as you want? Please explain

Comment: Well, I mean it's pretty simple isn't it. You have to have an even character number in a string: `12345678`. Sit in a loop peeling off the ends, towards the middle, `if ( ($str = $a . $b) =~/(AU|CG|U[AG]|G[CU])/ ) { print "found $1 at $loopvariable\r\n"; }`

Comment: @HåkonHægland Essentially I have ~10k sequences/strings. I can indicate to the program what positions I am interested in looking at and give it a regex. The program then goes line by line and extracts out the characters at those positions. I assume creates a new string with it, checks for a match with the regex, and if a match occurs it keeps the sequence and then moves on to the next line. So I can provide it a regex and tell it what to check against, but that's about it. It would be some work, but the best solution might just be to write a script from scratch so I have more functionality.

Comment: @Gingerbeardman When you give the position and the regex, for example `$pos = 10` and `$regex = qr/(?:AU|CG)|(?:U[AG]|G[CU])/`, will it then anchor the match to position 10 in the string, such that it will only look at positions 10 and 11, or will it look further down the string and check for matches at positions 11 and 12, and then 12 and 13, and so on?

Comment: @HåkonHægland It only looks at the positions I indicate. So I might tell it ``$pos = 10,12,14,17`` and then it will only use the characters at those 4 characters  (or however many I indicate) in the regex evaluation. Really I add a line under all of the sequences and add an ``X`` at the positions I want to look at and it extracts those. So unfortunately I also couldn't rearrange the positions to something like ``$pos = 10,17,12,14``.

Comment: @Gingerbeardman So if the string is `ACGU` and `$pos = 1,2` and `$regex` as above, it will not find the GU match at pos 3 and 4, since you constrained it to only look at pos 1 and 2?

Comment: @HåkonHægland Correct

Comment: @Gingerbeardman What if `$pos = 1,2,3` and regex as above.. now regex will match only two consecutive characters (due to the way the specific regex above is written), will it now try to match at pos 1,2 and then 2,3 ( with the above given specific regex), or will it produce an error, or will it only try to match at pos 1 and 2 and ignore pos 3?

Comment: @sln Ah, I see. I think I can make that work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, good luck then. If you want me to write that particular part, just let me know.

Comment: What version of Perl are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try generate the regexp given a set of patterns and positions. For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Regexp::Assemble;

my @patterns = qw( AU CG UA UG GC GU );
my @match_pos = qw( 14 23 );
my $pat_size = 4;
my $regex = build_regex( \@patterns, \@match_pos, $pat_size );

sub build_regex {
    my ( $patterns, $match_pos, $size ) = @_;
    my $ra = Regexp::Assemble->new();

    for my $pos_str ( @$match_pos ) {
        my @pos = map { $_ - 1 } split //, $pos_str;
        for my $pat_short ( @$patterns ) {
            my @pat = ('.') x $pat_size;
            my @chars = split //, $pat_short;
            @pat[@pos] = @chars;
            my $pat = join '', @pat;
            $ra->add($pat);
        }
    }
    my $regex = $ra->re;
    return $regex;
}
```

This regexp will match all the patterns at either positions 1 and 4 or at positions 2 or 3.

Comment: This blew my mind. I never even considered the possibility of writing a script that would output a regex. What a great idea!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just want to get two columns and see if they match your
regex pair.

There is no need to try and do this all in a single regex.

This is the faster way to do it. Use substr() to make your target, then
test it with the regex.

Keep all the input and output together in a structure.
In the below sample, this is the  *Que* hash.

It doesn't have to be so complicated.

Perl code

```
use strict;
use warnings;


my $FullSequence = 'AUGCCGU';

my %Que = (

 # structure:
 #  item =   col pair  ,  results ( target , match )
    '1' => [  1,    7,     '', '' ],
    '2' => [  2,    1,     '', '' ],
    '3' => [  2,    3,     '', '' ],
    '4' => [  5,    3,     '', '' ],
    '5' => [  5,    2,     '', '' ],
    '6' => [  2,    3,     '', '' ],

      # simple overlap test
    '7a' => [ 1,    2,     '', '' ],
    '7b' => [ 2,    3,     '', '' ],
    '7c' => [ 3,    4,     '', '' ],
    '7d' => [ 4,    5,     '', '' ],
    '7e' => [ 5,    6,     '', '' ],
    '7f' => [ 6,    7,     '', '' ],
);

# Process Que
  for my $key (keys %Que )
  {
     # Get target pair at column locations
      my $target = substr( $FullSequence, $Que{$key}->[0] - 1, 1 ) . substr( $FullSequence, $Que{$key}->[1] - 1, 1 );
      $Que{$key}->[2] = $target; 

     # Get match result of target
      if ( $target =~ /(AU|CG|U[AG]|G[CU])/ ) {
          $Que{$key}->[3] = $1;
          next;
      }
      $Que{$key}->[3] = 'no match';
  }

# Print Que result
  for my $key ( sort (keys %Que) )
  {
      print "item $key = ";
      print "cols (" . $Que{$key}->[0] . "," . $Que{$key}->[1] . ") ";
      print "result (" . $Que{$key}->[2]. ")  = " . $Que{$key}->[3] . "\n";

  }
```

Output

```
item 1 = cols (1,7) result (AU)  = AU
item 2 = cols (2,1) result (UA)  = UA
item 3 = cols (2,3) result (UG)  = UG
item 4 = cols (5,3) result (CG)  = CG
item 5 = cols (5,2) result (CU)  = no match
item 6 = cols (2,3) result (UG)  = UG
item 7a = cols (1,2) result (AU)  = AU
item 7b = cols (2,3) result (UG)  = UG
item 7c = cols (3,4) result (GC)  = GC
item 7d = cols (4,5) result (CC)  = no match
item 7e = cols (5,6) result (CG)  = CG
item 7f = cols (6,7) result (GU)  = GU
```